# Android Glide: correct way of using Signatures for cache

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I'm using the `Glide` libary to load images from `content://` URIs and remote URLs. I can't figure out how to set up the cache to invalidate entries when images change.

Some details:

1. My remote URLs are unique, no two different files will have the same URL. I can use the URL as the cache key (`signature`).
2. I think the `content://` URIs are not. I need to detect if the file behind a `content://` URI changed and reload the image from storage.

I'm not sure how to construct the correct `signature`. If it were a `File`, I could use the `lastModified()` timestamp, but I'm loading images on a `ListView` and using the `ContentResolver` to query each URI for metadata would destroy performance.

How is the cache signature for local media content used? How can I construct a signature unique for an image, even if the URI remains the same after a change? Is this scenario even possible, repeated URIs for different files over time?